# asp.net mvc include area's view to view search engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just created first area in the solution.
It looks like Areas/Reports.

All subfolders are autogenerated.
All configs and classes are autogenerated, i didnt touch them.

So i moved new controller and new view to their folders.

Before that i have @{Html.RenderPartial("AgreementReportsPartialView" ...
in my code, now view moved.

I only able to write @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Reports/Views/Shared/AgreementReportsPartialView.cshtml" to run the solution.

But how i can include my view(s) in area or my area at all, to search engine ?

I dont want to write full path in cshtml

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390045/asp-net-mvc-render-a-partial-view-from-an-area